# How does y=$x""$y perform reverse

Tags: shell

I used this code for reversing command line arguments that are in $@
my code is

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "enter a valid arguement" 
    exit
fi
for x in $@
do
    y=$x""$y
done
echo "the reverse is :$y"
```

I am unable to understand how this works.Can anyone help me?

Comment: use `set -vx` to see each line of code as it is executed. `set +vx` to turn off. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$@` takes all parameters, space separated (won't work right if the parameters contain spaces, use `"$@"` for that). Then the for loop takes the variable `y`, which starts empty, and puts the current parameter `x` in front of it: `y=$x""$y`. So if I have parameters `a` `b` `c`, then `y=a` ... `y="b a"` ... `y="c b a"`

Answer (score 0):

1. In SOF, use ```for code block, `for inline code.
2. This code loops over `$@`, and concat each one in front of the result(`$y`).

   - for example, when you have `./program.sh a b c`, `for` statement loop over `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, and in each loop `$y` is

     1. concat `"a"` to front of `"$y"`(`""`). result is `"a"`
     2. concat `"b"` to front of `"$y"`(`"a"`). result is `"ba"`
     3. concat `"c"` to front of `"$y"`(`"ba"`). result is `"cba"`

     by these steps, you get reversed string.

     If you add `" "` between `$x` and `$y`, you will get exact reversed string, i.e., `"c b a "`